Using a cell value as a name of sheet to call a value of a cell on that sheet
I have an excel file with multiple worksheet, the name of each Sheets are from a column in the first sheet like this
| A | B |
| ----- | ---------- |
| 3rd sheet name| |
| 4th sheet name | |
Can I use the value on column A to call sheet? E.G. if I want B column to be filled with cell D from the sheet listed on column A?
from What I know I need to type
='3rd sheet name'!D2
but can I somehow use column A's value since it is the name of the sheet I want to reference anyway?
I tried
='A2'!D2
='=INDEX(A2,1,1)'!D2
But Excel just open up an open file popup and when I cancel both return with "#REF!"
Anyone know how to do this? Preferably without macros
thanks beforehand!

Take a look into INDIRECT(), it would looke something like =INDIRECT(A2&"!D2") (where A2 contains sheet name)

Ohhh! It works, I never used that formula before, thanks!

maybe post the comment as an answer so I can close the question? Or should I just delete the post? Sorry I'm new here

To be honest, some research would've gotten you to a result. Anyway, welcome to the platform.

Take a look into INDIRECT(), it would looke something like =INDIRECT(A2&"!D2") (where A2 contains sheet name).
Sheet containing formula:

Sheet 3

